# Hello World in Elm with console / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, elm

Is there an easy, supported way in Elm of writing console applications, ideally in Node?  If so, what does the "Hello, World" look like?

I am aware that there are some packages, most of them not apparently maintained, that purport to do something like this, but they all seem like kludges to some degree.

Comment: Which packages did you look at, and what don't you like about them?

Comment: Elm does not officially support running outside of the browser yet - see the [roadmap](https://github.com/elm-lang/projects/blob/master/roadmap.md#can-i-use-elm-on-servers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elm is a frontend-only language as of 0.18. It might be backend-friendly in the future. But is it not right now. See [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/projects/blob/master/roadmap.md#can-i-use-elm-on-servers)

However, that doesn't meant that you can't use it with Node. You just need to use the "worker" mode and send all your data in and out through ports. For example:

```
port module Main exposing (..)

import Platform

port getName : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
port sendGreeting : String -> Cmd msg

type alias Model = {}

type Msg =
  GreetUser String

update msg model = 
  case msg of
    GreetUser name -> (model, sendGreeting name)

main = Platform.program 
  { init = ( {}, Cmd.none)
  , update = update
  , subscriptions = \model -> getName GreetUser
}
```

You can then compile it via `elm-make Main.elm --output elm.js` and require it in JS like so:

```
const Elm = require("./elm.js");
const app = Elm.Main.worker();

app.ports.sendGreeting.subscribe((greeting) => console.log(greeting));

app.ports.getName.send("Noah")
```

There are many apps that do this, such as:

- elm-sketch-importer
- elm-verify-examples
- elm-analyse
- elm-fuse